# having issues in running sample code for public-key cryptography in JS

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

newbie to JS and trying to reproduce the result of this code, [1] : bob encrypt the message for alice. In [2]: Alice decrypt the message. The private/public key is generated in [1] here 
`const bob = nacl.box.keyPair()
const alice = nacl.box.keyPair()`
  , how do I pass these keys in [2], since console.log does not print these keys?

```
// reading Alice key pair from secret key
const alice = nacl.box.keyPair.fromSecretKey(/* Uint8Array with 32-byte secret key */)
// reading Bob public key
const bob = {publicKey: /* Uint8Array with 32-byte secret key */}`
```

Many thanks for your input.

[1]

```
const nacl = require('tweetnacl')
nacl.util = require('tweetnacl-util')

// generating key pairs
const bob = nacl.box.keyPair()
const alice = nacl.box.keyPair()

// generating one time nonce for encryption
const nonce = nacl.randomBytes(24)
// message for Alice
const utf8 = 'Hello Alice'
// Bob encrypts message for Alice
const box = nacl.box(
  nacl.util.decodeUTF8(utf8),
  nonce,
  alice.publicKey,
  bob.secretKey
)

// somehow send this message to Alice
const message = {box, nonce}
```

[2]

```
const nacl = require('tweetnacl')
nacl.util = require('tweetnacl-util')

// reading Alice key pair from secret key
const alice = nacl.box.keyPair.fromSecretKey(/* Uint8Array with 32-byte secret key */)
// reading Bob public key
const bob = {publicKey: /* Uint8Array with 32-byte secret key */}

// const message = ... the message object from Bob
// Alice decrypts message from Bob
const payload = nacl.box.open(message.box, message.nonce, bob.publicKey, alice.secretKey)
const utf8 = nacl.util.encodeUTF8(payload) // <-- 'Hello Alice'
```

Comment: Why using public key crypto like this you only need to pass the public key

Comment: ummm, and how do I access that? when I do this `console.log(bob.publickey)`, it prints 'undefined' .

Comment: Ok I am going to give you a full answer

Answer (score 0):

So,

I don't know why your code isn't working but it's probably wrong somewhere.

I work in applied crypto, and I wrote up the following example to try and help you.

`tweetnacl` is fine and all, but in production systems you should use something like `libsodium`.

This code I wrote up shows how to do `elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman` and `EdDSA signature` in a JS binding for `libsodium`. **Also it will print bobs pub and private key.**

To get this lib, you need to do:

`npm install sodium-native` first...

```
function toHexString(byteArray) {
    return Array.from(byteArray, function(byte) {
        return ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join('')
}


//ECDH using curve25519
//totally fresh empty arrays

var alicePub = new Uint8Array(32);
var alicePriv = new Uint8Array(32);

var bobPub = new Uint8Array(32);
var bobPriv = new Uint8Array(32);


//fresh array to hold generated keys
var rxKey = new Uint8Array(sodium.crypto_kx_SESSIONKEYBYTES);
var txKey = new Uint8Array(sodium.crypto_kx_SESSIONKEYBYTES);

var otherRxKey = new Uint8Array(sodium.crypto_kx_SESSIONKEYBYTES);
var otherTxKey = new Uint8Array(sodium.crypto_kx_SESSIONKEYBYTES);


//generate key pairs for Alice and bob
sodium.crypto_kx_keypair(alicePub, alicePriv);
sodium.crypto_kx_keypair(bobPub, bobPriv);

//generate shared keys using ECDH
sodium.crypto_kx_client_session_keys(rxKey, txKey, alicePub, alicePriv, bobPub)
sodium.crypto_kx_server_session_keys(otherRxKey,otherTxKey, bobPub, bobPriv, alicePub)



console.log("ECDH Key Exchange, rx, tx")
console.log(rxKey, txKey)
console.log(otherRxKey, otherTxKey)

console.log(bobPub, bobPriv)








//signature using Ed25519
var publicKey = new Uint8Array(sodium.crypto_sign_PUBLICKEYBYTES);
var privateKey = new Uint8Array(sodium.crypto_sign_SECRETKEYBYTES);
sodium.crypto_sign_keypair(publicKey, privateKey);

var message = new Uint8Array([0,0,1,2,128]);
var similarMessage = new Uint8Array([0,1,1,2,128]);

//sign and message
var signedMessage = new Uint8Array(sodium.crypto_sign_BYTES + message.length)

sodium.crypto_sign(signedMessage, message, privateKey);
console.log("signedMessage: %s", signedMessage);


//verify it works
var bool = sodium.crypto_sign_verify_detached(signedMessage, message, publicKey)
var bool2 = sodium.crypto_sign_verify_detached(signedMessage, similarMessage, publicKey)
console.log("Real message:%s",message, bool);
console.log("Fake message:%s",similarMessage, bool2);
```

Output:

```
ECDH Key Exchange, rx, tx
Uint8Array(32) [
   67,  47, 133,  36, 228, 190, 228, 192,
  193,  16, 142, 142,  25,  97, 124,   2,
    4, 210, 194,  51,  29,  25, 148,  70,
   50,  30, 215, 107, 154,  52,  19, 180
] Uint8Array(32) [
  219,  28,  88, 238,  33, 174, 171,  81,
  173, 197,  38,  38, 254, 160, 142, 138,
   66, 216,   5,  65, 238,  94,  62, 183,
   89,  61, 151, 137, 220, 108,   4, 161
]
Uint8Array(32) [
  219,  28,  88, 238,  33, 174, 171,  81,
  173, 197,  38,  38, 254, 160, 142, 138,
   66, 216,   5,  65, 238,  94,  62, 183,
   89,  61, 151, 137, 220, 108,   4, 161
] Uint8Array(32) [
   67,  47, 133,  36, 228, 190, 228, 192,
  193,  16, 142, 142,  25,  97, 124,   2,
    4, 210, 194,  51,  29,  25, 148,  70,
   50,  30, 215, 107, 154,  52,  19, 180
]
bobs keys
Uint8Array(32) [
  235,  23,  39, 184,   8, 74, 147,  55,
   88, 230, 185,  51, 137, 47,  12, 246,
  247, 235, 204,  57,  99, 78, 143, 131,
  161,  24,  71, 185, 171, 23,  30, 215
] Uint8Array(32) [
   79, 224,  52,  64, 235, 231,  82, 236,
   10, 169, 210, 156, 249, 182,  60,  27,
  173, 160, 150,  31,   8,  20, 217, 215,
   58, 172, 185, 230, 185, 185,  67,   0
]
signedMessage: 134,97,230,121,91,96,87,17,1,55,95,20,176,7,203,124,116,236,31,140,173,32,129,206,82,174,214,188,177,45,30,80,230,6,203,204,140,216,228,69,106,134,196,175,95,139,140,116,239,27,235,49,245,24,130,129,154,175,126,127,206,163,206,11,0,0,1,2,128
Real message:0,0,1,2,128 true
Fake message:0,1,1,2,128 false
```

So as you can see I get out bobs key pair, but really, elliptic curves are used for two main things:

1) to digitally sign things

2) to agree a key for symmetric (AES/ChaCha/Salsa) encryption

Remember, the public key in ECC is just a point on the curve.
The private key is just a large number which you scalar multiple by a special point on the curve called the generator to get the public key.

This code represents the type of approach we see in production systems, it's side channel resistant and uses grown up libs.